# Iterate functions that uses pointer with for loop

Tags: c++, pointers

```
int main()
{
    using namespace std;
    int i=3;
    radius *Zone1;
    Zone1=ZoneSorting(6088, i);
    zone *ZONE;
    ZONE=ZoneGeneration(rN, rA, rB, rC, 6088);
    CentralLocalHeliostatDetector(i, ZONE[i], Zone1, 10);
    getch();
}
```

This works fine! Now I want to repeat this for i=0 to i=32
So i tried this. But it gives crashes...

```
int main()
{
    using namespace std;

    radius *Zone1;
    zone *ZONE;
    ZONE=ZoneGeneration(rN, rA, rB, rC, 6088);

    for(int i=1; i<32; i++)
    {
        Zone1=ZoneSorting(6088, i);
        CentralLocalHeliostatDetector(i, ZONE[i], Zone1, 10);
        cout<<"===================="<<endl;
        delete[] Zone1;
    }
    getch();
}
```

Comment: Can you provide more information on the ZoneSorting(), CentralLocalHeliostatDetector() and ZoneGeneration() functions? Also try to set a breakpoint at the beginning of the loop and step through it to see when exactly it crashes and what's the state of the variables at that point. My initial guess would be that it has to do something with the delete statement at the end of the loop but I can't say more until I know what those two functions actually do.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you calling delete?  This is for deleting a heap object allocated with the new operator.  If you want a new ZoneSorting object named Zone1 each time through  the loop, you can just do

```
for(int i=1; i<32; i++)
{
   ZoneSorting Zone1(6088, i);
   CentralLocalHeliostatDetector(i, ZONE[i], Zone1, 10);
   cout<<"===================="<<endl;
}
```

Of course, I'm not sure I really understand what your code is supposed to be doing, as other responders have remarked.

Answer (score -1):

Try to remove the `delete[] Zone1;` line from the for loop boundaries.
Or if you need it,try replacing it with `delete[i] Zone1;`

Comment: Unless ZoneSorting() returns an array...That is why more info is needed on what those functions do. :-/